# What does this equals sign mean?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I found this article on WolframMathWorld describing Catalan's identity found 
[here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CatalansIdentity.html) and I was wondering what the second equals sign meant.

$$(x^2 +y^2 +z^2)^3 =\left[x(=3z^2 -x^2 -y^2)\right]^2 +\left[y(3z^2 -x^2 -y^2)\right]^2 \\ +\left[z(z^2 -3x^2 -3y^2)\right]^2.$$

Comment: Looks like a typo.

Comment: Yes, there is a typo in MathWorld.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner.  Your edit makes the question incomprehensible. I suggest you undo it.